# In databases, is row level locking an example of ACID, optimistic concurrency, or both?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, acid

simultaneous writes
Also what happens in a nosql database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll ignore the NoSQL part, otherwise I would have to close the question as too unfocused.

Row level locking is a technique that relational databases use to provide *isolation*, which is the I of ACID. Isolation means that concurrent database sessions are isolated from each other – the database tries to keep them from being influenced by each other's activities.

Specifically, if two concurrent sessions try to modify the same data row, they have to “take turns”: the second one has to wait until the transaction of the first session is done. This wait is usually very short and does not hurt, but it prevents inconsisiencies (*consistency* is the C of ACID).

Row level locking, and locking in general, are part of *pessimistic locking*: you lock a row to prevent other sessions from messing with the row while you are working on it. It is done with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. It is called “pessimistic” because it reflects a mindset like “I expect someone will try to modify the row while I am working on it, so let's lock it to be sure”.

*Optimistic locking* is ill-named, because no locks are actually taken. You don't prevent concurrent transactions from modifying the row you are interested in. Instead you check afterwards if the row has been modified by a concurrent transaction or not, and if it has, you try the operation again.

Comment: is this also the case when a database encounters two writes at precisely the same time? I mean both have the **exact** timestamps

Comment: If they affect the same row, one of them gets the roe lock, and the other one had to wait.